# Spelling Similarities in English and Spanish but not in Italian and Spanish

Tags: etymology, language-change, indo-european, germanic-languages, romance-languages

The spelling of the word 'admit' has a ⟨d⟩ in both English and the Spanish equivalent, *admitir*, but not in Italian *ammettere*. Why is the ⟨d⟩ absent in the Italian equivalent?

Answer (score 4):

It would make more sense if you asked where the d went to, rather than how it got there. These words come from Latin admittere. The d is retained in English and Spanish, but assimilated to the following m in Italian ammettere.

Answer (score 2):

*admitir* is not the inherited form of Latin *admittere* in Spanish (i.e. it has not undergone the normal Latin > Spanish sound changes), but a later restoration based on the Latin form. If *admittere* had come down from Latin to Spanish without restoration, it would probably look something like "*ameter*". (Compare Sp. *atenerse* "to adjust (to something)" < Latin *attinere se*.)

By contrast, Italian *ammettere* is either inherited from *admittere*, or was restored and then adapted to the expected Latin > Italian sound changes.

Many other common Spanish words (perhaps more than in Italian, overall) are restorations from Latin, and they often co-exist with a more obscure word that has the same origin, but has developed through the Latin > Spanish sound changes: for example, *rápido* (*raudo*), *regla* (*reja*), *quieto* (*quedo*), etc.

Answer (score -1):

We don't have any word in Italian with DM together, without vowels in between.